# Get string piece after last symbols "/" or "\"

Tags: javascript, regex

I need get from  string,  piece after last  `\` or `/`, that is from this string  `C:\fake\path\some.jpg` result must be `some.jpg`

I tried this:

```
var str = "C:\fake\path\some.jpg";
var newstr = str.replace(/[^\\\/]+$/, "");
alert(newstr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J4GdN/3/

but not works, what is right regex for this?

Comment: Well your str needs to be `var str = "C:\\fake\\path\\some.jpg";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well your str needs to be escaped `\\` for it to work correctly. You also need to use match since the reg exp you are using is matching the end, not the start.

```
var str = "C:\\fake\\p\ath\some.jpg";
var newstr = str.match(/[^\\/]+$/);
alert(newstr);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QBgLs/)

Answer (score 11):

You don't need a regex to do it, this should work:

```
var newstr = str.substring(Math.max(str.lastIndexOf("\\"), str.lastIndexOf("/")) + 1);
```

Comment: Don't forget to account for `/` as well.

Comment: But the solution requires multiple string lookups for the index, not the greatest solution.

Comment: @epascarello I upvoted your solution in fact because it's shorter, but I personally prefer avoiding regex until I don't have any other choice.

Comment: I ran the tests and the substring is faster http://jsperf.com/testing-indexof-vs-reg-exp-for-endofline [I had a feeling it would be since reg exp are normally slow]

Comment: @epascarello nice, thanks for the information and for making me discover jsperf.com, didn't know about that one !

Answer (score 1):

first, let's escape the backslashes

```
var str = "C:\\fake\\path\\some.jpg";
var newstr = str.replace(/[^\\\/]+$/, "");
alert(newstr);
```

now, you are removing `some.jpg` instead of getting it as the result.

here are a few options to fix this:

1.replace with a regex

```
var newstr = str.replace(/.*[\\\/]/, "");
```

2.split with regex (doesn't work in all browsers)

```
var tmp = str.split(/\\|\//);
var newstr = tmp[tmp.length-1];
```

4.as said here, match

```
var newstr = str.match(/.*[\\\/](.*)/)[1];
```